# Backup and recovery of directory on AWS Directory Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-directory-services

I was looking at ways to backup AWS managed Directory Service.

I had a look at some articles like [Backup Active Directory](https://activedirectorypro.com/backup-active-directory/), but looks like they talk about backing up when we have access to domain controllers.

But I do not think we are allowed to access the DCs of a directory, and using snapshots like [Snapshot or restore your directory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_snapshots.html) wouldn't work either if the directory is deleted.

Any suggestions? Problem at the moment is that the directory created was with legacy pipelines, and there may be a chance for it to be deleted by terraform if we run it again.

Comment: What directory service are you looking at? Doesn't AWS do backups already?

Comment: Looking at Microsoft AD